# why doesn't it want to add a post or category?

Tags: php, mysqli

As a school assignment I need to make a cms, in that I need to be able to make post edit them and delete them. so for i can edit and delete them, but for some reason I cant get it to insert the post(and also the categories, same almost the same) I hope you guys can help me.

Here is the code:

The form

```
   <form action="includes/doAddpost.php" method="post">
      <label for="PostName">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="PostName" id="PostName" placeholder="Title" autofocus="auto"/>
      <label for="PostAuthor">Author</label>
      <input type="text" name="PostAuthor" id="PostAuthor" placeholder="Authors name"
      value="<?php if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
      echo $_SESSION['username'];
      }
      ?>"/>
      <label for="PostContent">Content</label>
      <textarea name="PostContent" id="PostContent" placeholder="content"></textarea>
      <label for="PostCats">category</label>
      <select name="PostCats">
      <?php
      $query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
      while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      ?>
      <option value="<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"><<?php echo $cat['title']; ?></option>
      <?php } ?>
```

and this part doesnt seem to work either

```
 </select>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
   </form>
```

Here is the doAddpost page:

```
<?php
include '../../includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(isset($_POST['PostName'])){
        if(isset($_POST['PostContent'])){
        addPost($mysqli,$_POST['PostName'],$_POST['PostAuthor'], $_POST['PostContent'],$_POST['PostCats']);
        header("Location: ../posts.php");
        }else{
            echo"please enter some content!";
        }
    } else{
        echo"please set a category name!";
        include('../addpost.php');
    }
}else{
    header("Location: ../addpost.php");
}
?>
```

and the function:

```
function addPost($mysqli, $pName, $pAuthor, $pContent, $pCat = 1)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO posts VALUES ('$pName', '$pAuthor', '$pContent', $pCat)";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue I am facing ?

Comment: What was the error you got...??

Comment: @SherinJose i didnt got any error

Comment: which page is loaded finally after adding...

Comment: @SherinJose the posts.php page

Comment: You query  `$query = "SELECT * FROM categories";$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);` working? Just want to check your connection are ok or not?

Comment: just edit in your addPost function ...mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error());....and try...If any mysql error occured you can find it

Comment: @Roopendra no it doesnt, and i dont get why it shout work i though.

Comment: @SherinJose when i do that i got this: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: how many columns are in your database table....??

Comment: @SherinJose there are 5 tables but i found one of the errors i didn't add a null for the id colum. but the categories select still doesn't work

Comment: just try my answer...i posted it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just edit your function as ,

```
function addPost($mysqli, $pName, $pAuthor, $pContent, $pCat = 1)
{
    $query = "INSERT INTO posts (`your_column1`, `your_column_2`, `your_column_3`, `your_column_4`) VALUES ('$pName', '$pAuthor', '$pContent', $pCat)";
    mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

and then try...

Also in you select list change it as,

```
<option value="<?php echo $cat['id']; ?>"><?php echo $cat['title']; ?></option>
```

You placed an extra `<` there in your code..check that...:)

Comment: this works great now but when i am adding a posts i cant select a category i got the amount of categories but the selector is blank. edit in the databse it does give me the wright id of it

Comment: Is the select box is blank...i mean no datas in the list..??

Comment: yep i think i dont echo the title wright, but i can t see why it doesn't wanna do it

Comment: just use `var_dump($cat);` inside while loop...and look whether the array contains anything...

Comment: this is what is inside of the $cat variable: 

   ` <select name="PostCats">
                                    array(3) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      string(1) "1"
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(7) "General"
      ["description"]=&gt;
      string(35) "general things i like to talk about"
    }  </option><option value="2">
                                    array(3) {
      ["id"]=&gt;
      string(1) "3"
      ["title"]=&gt;
      string(12) "editted test"
      ["description"]=&gt;
      string(24) "this is a editted testjb"
    }`

Comment: and                                    </option><option value="3">
                                array(3) {
  ["id"]=&gt;
  string(1) "7"
  ["title"]=&gt;
  string(5) "jnhgf"
  ["description"]=&gt;
  string(8) "gvfrsdcs"
}
                                    </option><option value="7">
                                                            </option></select>

Comment: cant dont have enough reputation

Comment: hey can u help me one more time: i try to edit the post now but it gives me a error:Unknown column 'author' in 'field list' that coms from:         $query = "UPDATE categories SET title = '$pName', author = '$pAuthor', content = '$pContent', categoryid = '$pCat' WHERE ID = $id ";
the first thing i thought it was, was the database but there the name is set correctly. please help

Answer (score 0):

Now its time to step by step debugging:-

1) change your select category mysqli_query as below for debugging purpose

```
mysqli_query( $mysqli , $query ) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."($query)");
```

2) for you insert query mention column name in which you want to insert record . as you mentioned in comment you dont want id null so you should make you id column as `AUTOINCREMENT`

e.g

```
INSERT INTO posts (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`,`column4`) VALUES ('$pName', '$pAuthor', '$pContent', $pCat);
```

Comment: this works great now but when i am adding a posts i cant select a category i got the amount of categories but the selector is blank. edit in the databse it does give me the wright id of it